# I need help solving this riddle!

Tags: riddle

> You walk 30 feet and turn left, you walk another 30 feet and turn left, you continue to walk 30 feet and turn left, and you do this one more time.

Where are you?

*Hint: The answer is not where you started, but you can use this to help get the answer*

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE!  Is this a riddle you created yourself (and if not, could you provide attribution?)

Comment: Does "turn left" imply a 90 degree turn?  If not, it depends on the angle(s) that you are turning.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your initial direction was north, you are now

> 30 feet north,30 feet west

because

> "do this one more time" means do the "3 steps" one more time. So you walked 30 feet a total of 6 times, not 4 times.

Answer (score 4):

You are

> home. 30 feet is the distance between the bases on a baseball diamond.

Comment: Isn't it around 80-90 feet?

Comment: Darn. Should have looked that up.
30 feet isn't even used in Little League.

Comment: Matches my initial thoughts, but googling told me No.

Answer (score 3):

Using a baseball diamond you would be at 2nd base.

```
  START ->  h
 1st 30 -> /
          1   3  <- END
 2nd 30 -> \ / <- 3rd 30
            2
```

Doing this one more time:

```
            h
 5th 30 -> / \ <- 4th 30
          1   3 <- START
 6th 30 -> \ /
     END -> 2
```

Leaving you on second base

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say without any other reference, but you may be

> 30 feet south of the North Pole,

or

> 30 feet north of the South Pole.

Comment: Why only N or S? it could be any direction, as it depends from the first direction

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is:

> 30 feet to the left of where you started

because

> The "this" that you're told to do one more time is "turn left". So you've walked 3 sides of a square and then turned so that you're facing the same direction as you were originally

Answer (score 0):

You are

> 30 feet to the left of where, and how, you started walking, facing  original direction

Because

> "you do this one more time." is the left turn, not the walk and left turn.  So you take three walks and turn left four times.  Assuming you start facing north:
>  Walk North, Face West, Walk West, Face South, Walk South, Face East, Face North.  The North/South walks cancel so you end up 30ft west facing North

Answer (score 0):

you are walking on

> 3d shape, like pyramid.

shown as below

> [image]

imagine that you start walking

> from any corner point to the top 30 feet and so on (for simplicity you can assume every corner is 30 feet long) you will not end up where you start since you go up and down etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are

> Under the ground

because

> I'll assume you're not doing this "one more time", but you "do this one"(turn left) "more time" (probably a lot more), wich means you kind of drill the ground and ends up under the ground